# The type or namespace name 'GvrControllerInput' could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-vr, daydream

In Unity3d, my build goes fine, runs fine on my Android Nougat.

However, I'm trying to get access to the controller in a RigidBody Update method.

I have a GvrControllerInput Component added above the Rigid Body First Person Controller.

The following lines:

```
    private void Update()
    {
       RotateView();
                // Example: get controller's current orientation:
       Quaternion ori =  GvrController.Orientation;
...
    }
```

I get the following error:
The type or namespace name 'GvrControllerInput' could not be found.

What is weird to me is where are the namespaces added for the controller or ANY of the Daydream objects??

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using?  A trivial test using 2017.1 and the 1.7 sdk seems to work.

Comment: I'm using v1.70.0.

This just doesn't make sense. I added the asset as a custom package to the project (GoogleVRForUnity_1.70.0.unitypackage), yet if I go into my RigidBody Controller script GvrControllerInput just doesn't resolve. Can't make any sense of it.